# Comment appelle-t-on, dans un texte de théâtre, le nom du personnage précédant la réplique?

Tags: terminologie, théatre

Les textes de théâtre sont généralement écrit dans un formalisme

```
<Nom>: <Réplique>
```

ou

```
<Nom>
<Réplique>
```

Par exemple:

```
Luc: Où sont les œufs?
Marie: Dans le garde-manger.
```

Dans cet exemple, comment appelle-t-on `Luc` et `Marie`?
Et est-ce que le texte de la réplique se nomme bien *réplique* ou si un terme plus précis existe?

Merci

Comment: Oui assurément! Le nom du personnage est bien le nom du personnage. ;-) Oui pour la *réplique* aussi pour un terme en général. Il peut exister des termes plus précis comme *tirade* (s'il s'agit d'une réplique longue) ou encore *apareté* si la réplique est prononcée à part.

Comment: [Le vocabulaire du théâtre](http://www.ralentirtravaux.com/lettres/sequences/sixieme/medecin-volant/vocabulaire-du-theatre.php). De très nombreux autres sites et aussi wikipedia [Lexique théâtral](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_th%C3%A9%C3%A2tral).

Comment: @aCOSwt: C'est plutôt « Aparté. »

Comment: @Toto : Oui! Bien sûr! Tu as raison. **un aparté** Merci pour ton regard attentif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le nom du personnage fait partie des **[didascalies](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didascalie_(th%C3%A9%C3%A2tre))**.
Selon wikipédia, on l'appelerait "**didascalie nominative**."

Et vous avez raison, la réplique se nomme bien une réplique, avec des noms spécialisés en fonction du type de réplique (voir un lexique du théâtre).